# Spring boot 2.1.x app with log4j2 only dependency starting twice it seems

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

Dependencies in POM

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now running in debug mode as true the app is logging like its starting twice. I'm using STS eclipse dev enviornment.

```
12:34:24.576 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application started with classpath: [file:/D:/STS-%20My%20Research%20Workspace/bootresearch/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-expression-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-jcl-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.23/snakeyaml-1.23.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j2/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-log4j2-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.11.1/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.11.1/log4j-api-2.11.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.11.1/log4j-core-2.11.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-jul/2.11.1/log4j-jul-2.11.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.25/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar]
12:34:24.576 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application started with classpath: [file:/D:/STS-%20My%20Research%20Workspace/bootresearch/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-expression-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-jcl-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.23/snakeyaml-1.23.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j2/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-log4j2-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.11.1/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.11.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.11.1/log4j-api-2.11.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.11.1/log4j-core-2.11.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-jul/2.11.1/log4j-jul-2.11.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/test/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.25/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.2.RELEASE)

12:34:24.610 [main] INFO  com.research.boot.App - Starting App on mymachine with PID 12688 (started by test in D:\STS- My Research Workspace\bootresearch)
12:34:24.610 [main] INFO  com.research.boot.App - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
12:34:24.610 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Loading source class com.research.boot.App
12:34:24.610 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Loading source class com.research.boot.App
12:34:24.626 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener - Loaded config file 'file:/D:/STS-%20My%20Research%20Workspace/bootresearch/target/classes/application.yml' (classpath:/application.yml)
12:34:24.626 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener - Loaded config file 'file:/D:/STS-%20My%20Research%20Workspace/bootresearch/target/classes/application.yml' (classpath:/application.yml)
12:34:24.877 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.admin.SpringApplicationAdminMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin - Application Admin MBean registered with name 'org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication'
12:34:24.877 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.admin.SpringApplicationAdminMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin - Application Admin MBean registered with name 'org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication'
```

Spring Boot app class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App 
{
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(App.class);
    public static void main( String[] args)
    {
        logger.info("starting");
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
        logger.info("Started");
    }
}
```

This is causing the JMS listener topics twice in my regular application and then I was able to drill it down back to log4j2 dependency in a sample boot project. If I remove the log4j2 dependency then it starts once. Not sure what is wrong here.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to set the **additivity** property on your logger to **false**. Otherwise it's **set to true by default** and will result in multiple log statements.

In code this would look like:

```
logger.setadditivity(false);
```

Comment: That was simple catch. Thanks. Need to check why my JMSListener object is getting registered twice.

Comment: np, glad it helped